# When to Commit Unit Of Work using SignalR?

Tags: signalr, ravendb, unit-of-work

I'm trying to use the Unit Of Work pattern with RavenDb and SignalR. However, I can't find a clear SignalR Hub event to use as the hook to call SaveChanges on my RavenDb document session.

If it was MVC I'd use Application_EndRequest in Global.asax or OnActionExecuted in my Controller, but what equivalent is there for a SignalR Hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a custom [Hub pipeline module](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline) that overrides the [`HubPipelineModule.OnAfterIncoming`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline) method.

`OnAfterIncoming` will be called upon the completion of each Hub method.

Comment: Thanks. I did spy this method, but it wasn't clear if it does what I'm after. I think it's because there is an [OnAfterOutgoing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.hubpipelinemodule.onafteroutgoing(v=vs.111).aspx) method as well. Can you shed any light on that? I'll put in some trace statements in my code to see the order of evaluation

Comment: So this is the order of events (assuming your Hub method sends a message to a client): OnBeforeIncoming, OnBeforeOutgoing, OnAfterOutgoing, OnAfterIncoming. Looks good to me, consider your answer accepted!

Comment: The OnBeforeOutgoing and OnAfterOutgoing methods are similar to OnBeforeIncoming and OnAfterIncoming but for invocations in the opposite direction. The Incoming methods are for *client-to-server* calls, whereas the Outgoing methods for *server-to-client* calls.

Comment: One other key difference between OnAfterIncoming and OnAfterOutgoing is that OnAfterIncoming executes after the server-side Hub method completes while OnAfterOutgoing may execute before clients receive the Hub method invocation. OnAfterOutgoing does indicate indicate a hub invocation message has successfully been published to a message bus however.